# Java - Refering to other subclass

Tags: java, if-statement

I've been learning Java for a good couple of months but I really don't seem to learn it well. I've been attempting to make REALLY simple programs by myself instead of watching tutorials but a "game" this simple already gives me so much headache.

Anyway I'm trying to write a simple console based game. The program generates an integer from 0-100 and you have to guess it, it either says the number is greater or smaller. Simple right?

I have two problems: 
1) It will only run once, if the scanner value is not correct, it says the random number is greater/smaller and you can input another integer, BUT there's no response for the second input.
2) --> So I thought it's because it will generate new value for "goal" and there's some kind of conflict, so I decided to put "goal" generation in a separate subclass. But no. I just don't understand how to use the "goal" value in the if/else block.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGame {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int num, numIn;

    int goal = GetMath.goal; 
    //      TRIED THIS WITHOUT SEPARATE CLASS TOO:
    final class GetMath{
    int goal = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random()*101);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter an integer from 0 to 100");
    //numIn = -1; ---- SOMETHING I TRIED
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    numIn = in.nextInt();




    if(numIn>goal){
        System.out.println("It's smaller than " + numIn);
        in.nextInt();
        return;
    }else if(numIn<goal){
        System.out.println("It's greater than " + numIn);
        in.nextInt();
        return;
    } else if(numIn==goal){
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you win the game!");

    } else {

        System.out.println("Please, enter an integer from 0 to 100");
        in.nextInt();
        return;
    }
```

Now the line

```
int goal = GetMath.goal;
```

gives an error

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field GetMath.goal
```

If I change "int goal" to "static int goal", "int static goal" will give an error and asking to delete word "static" in the said line.

I hope someone understands, I not very good at coding jargon :D

Comment: Why are you using a separate class at all? Why aren't you just using `int goal = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random()*101);`?

Comment: Also the `GetMath` class definition is weirdly placed.

Comment: I thought it will run the Mat.Random again and generate a new number. The integer must be the same value at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static reference error comes because you are calling on a nested class that hasn't been initialised. If you make the GetMath class static, I think that will fix the problem. However, its not really that necessary.

The actual problem you're having is the second go round. What your program does is ask for a new integer (the else at the end) and then stop. That return on the penultimate line is ending the program. Instead, you want to stick everything after you declare goal into a loop (while or for is fine, though I'd put a number limit on it to avoid infinite loops). Then, if the wrong number is entered you go around again.

I guess the confusion lies in what `return` does. It doesn't start you over. It ends the method call and passes back what you give it. Instead of what you've done, only have the return value when you want the program to close.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
System.out.println("Enter an integer from 0 to 100");
    //numIn = -1; ---- SOMETHING I TRIED
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    numIn = in.nextInt();

    if(numIn==goal){
    System.out.println("Congratulations, you win the game!");
    return 0; //return 0 indicates a normal completion of the program
    }...etc
}
System.out.println("Out of turns. Too bad, you lose...") //Just a suggestion, but an explanation of why the game just stopped is good, no?
return 0;
```

Comment: Okay, looks much better! However for some reason, if I use return 0, I have to change the main class name to "public static int main(String[] args){"(at least that's how Eclipse proposes to solve the error on the return 0 line), and when I do that, I get an exception that says I must use "public static void main".

Comment: Sorry, I'm in C++ mode apparently. In that case, you can bring the 'out of turns' warning into the loop dependent on an if(i == 24) and replace the 'win' `return` with a `break;`. 

That'll let the loop finish naturally if you run out of turns (with a warning of the reason) and a win will end it all prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) It will only run once, if the scanner value is not correct, it says the random number is greater/smaller and you can input another integer, BUT there's no response for the second input.

If I didn't miss anything you're not using a loop of any kind, thus your application will read the player's input, check it and print a message and then terminates.

> 2) --> So I thought it's because it will generate new value for "goal" and there's some kind of conflict, so I decided to put "goal" generation in a separate subclass. But no. I just don't understand how to use the "goal" value in the if/else block.

You don't need a separate class, just assign a new value to `goal` when the player guessed it right.

I'll try and make a brief example of what your game should look like (just a bare bone so you'll need to extend it):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
  Random random = new Random(); //more convenient than Math.random()
  int goal = random.nextInt(101);

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  while(true) { //run until the loop terminates itself calling return
    //get the player's guess
    System.out.println("Enter an integer from 0 to 100");       
    int numIn = in.nextInt();

    //TODO: check that numIn is in range 0 to 100     

    //now check 
    if(numIn>goal){
      System.out.println("It's smaller than " + numIn + "\nPlease try again.");
    } else if(numIn<goal){
      System.out.println("It's greater than " + numIn + "\nPlease try again.");
    } else{ //if the number is not greater or smaller it mut be equal
      System.out.println("Congratulations, you win the game! Play again? (y/n)");
      //read the answer here and if it is "y" then assign a new value to goal, otherwise call return to end the game.
      String answer = in.next();
      if( answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y") ) {
        goal = random.nextInt(101);
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally some comments on your code (and maybe assumptions):

```
int goal = GetMath.goal; 
//      TRIED THIS WITHOUT SEPARATE CLASS TOO:
final class GetMath{
int goal = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random()*101);
}
```

This won't work since `GetMath.goal` would need to be a static variable which isn't the case. Even if it was, it would be initialized only once the way you're doing it.

*If* you'd do it like that (but as already said this isn't necessary here and I'd consider that approach bad design anyways), you should call `int goal = new GetMath().goal;` in order to create a new instance of `GetMath` which has it's instance variable `goal` initialized to a new random number and then read that variable.

But once again: *this is bad design and not necessary anyways*.

> If I change "int goal" to "static int goal", "int static goal" will give an error and asking to delete word "static" in the said line.

That depend's on where you put the `static` keyword. It needs to be put in front of the type (`int`) and in your case only would be allowed for `goal` in `GetMath`, i.e.

```
class GetMath {
  static int goal = ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for helping. Some real good information here and got my game to work! I'm gonna try mixing this with Felix's for method and see how it ends up. Thanks for everything Thomas :)

Answer (score 0):

First, as John suggests - no need for the GetMath class. Second, your logic is all in the main method. Instead, create a method in NumberGame and put the logic there. The reason it is asking for input only once is because you only call Scanner nextInt() once. You need to put that in a loop and exit the loop only if the numIn equals the goal. Also, the num integer is not used. Good luck.